# Bar between "add a comment" and "show more comments" is inconsistent

Tags: feature-request, comments, design

I can't help but notice that the separator is inconsistent with the rest of the site.

> right below the question  [image]
>
> right after the comments [image]

Proposed change

> margin 2px [image] <- probably this
>
> margin 0px [image]

Instead of

```
<span class="js-link-separator">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
```

use

```
<span class="lsep">|</span>
```

Comment: I am amazed by the sharpness of your vision. What is your ophthalmologist? Could you recommend him/her to all of us seniors? :-)

Comment: @Steve I usually have all webpages zoomed in more than 150%, that's how I got [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225821/stack-exchange%E2%84%A2-multicollider-superdropdown%E2%84%A2-image-wacked) too.

Comment: And the age doesn't hurt for sure .... :-)

Comment: "add a comment" and "show x more comments" have more words, so it's reasonable that they should have a wider separator.

Comment: @Boann Mainly it's about the color, I prefer the 2px because it does feel less squished.

Comment: @Steve: Does the black separator between gray text *not* stand out to you? For me, it was the first thing I noticed.

Comment: @ruakh oh well, let's have this talk in 25 years from now...

Comment: @Steve: Sounds good. I'll add it to my calendar. :-)

Comment: @DaveChen : I just would be for removing the separator.

Comment: This is what I love about developers, full on pedantry!

Comment: [Another bar that needs adjusting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XDlWu.jpg) as its a bit moved to the left. Added red vertical lines to show the wrong alignment of the bar at the middle

Answer (score 12):

I agree: why have different types of separators?

They should be consistent with a site's design: MSE's design doesn't use separators, so why does the new comment layout have them?

MSE design:

[image: MSE Toolbar]

MSE comment layout:

[image: MSE Comments]

Fixed:

[image: Fixed design]

This should definitely be fixed.

In the meantime, however, I've created [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/4819/comment-separator-fix) that implements your suggested change on each SE site to follow the design of its toolbars.

<del>The only snag I ran into with your suggestion was that the separator is still present when the comments don't overflow. It is merely hidden with the addendum `dno` to the class name, so you have to check to make sure that that is not present before changing the `span`'s class (which would make it unnecessarily visible).</del>

Trying to get around the way that Stack Exchange's dev team has implemented the show/hide behavior has created quite a few versions that try to replicate the proper workings of the comment system (see the revision history), but I've rewritten it in a way that should comply with SE's design and be future-proof (version 2.0). Until/if this is (not) fixed, the userscript should, for all intents and purposes, work the way that toolbars (<kbd>share</kbd>/<kbd>edit</kbd>/<kbd>close</kbd>/<kbd>delete</kbd>/<kbd>flag</kbd>) do on all sites in the network.

It makes the separator look like this (for SO):

[image: New separator]

That's much more in line with the separators for the toolbar:

[image: Existing toolbar]

Comment: Separators between widely spaced single-word hyperlinks don't seem to really add anything. But between sentence fragments...

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe, but it should be consistent. That said, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DCGbH.png) is the definition of the `lsep` class for MSE, which is used for separators site-wide (it's hidden), so part of MSE's design is, quite literally, no separators (from what I can tell).

Comment: @Deduplicator Also, it's up to SE whether they want to keep or remove the separator (which is still in a trial period at this point) on MSE, but I'm using whatever each site uses for separators in the userscript for the sake of simplicity. Either way, it definitely should be changed from what it is now (at least on SO and similar sites).

Comment: Per AstroCB's suggestion, this fix is now also included in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.20. Thanks! (The SOUP implementation differs slightly, in that it keeps the existing separator elements and just adds the `lsep` class and removes the `&nbsp;`s, but the result should look identical.)